# its posibily its posibily its posibily its posibily

Tags: html, css

its posibily  its posibily  its posibily  its posibily  its posibily  its posibily  its posibily

Comment: Isn't the text itself a content?

Comment: use "display:table-cell"  and vertical-align:middle  for text middle

Comment: It;s not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to center this div vertically & horizontally on the page?

Comment: use the display properti :) http://jsfiddle.net/nju2ecby/1/

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3):

You can realize that by deleting the styles of the span (or the span completely) and display the `.container` as a table-cell. Table-cells will allow you to vertical align the text in it.

Like this:

```
.container {
    background:#010101;
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#fff;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nju2ecby/2/)

Comment: i see your fiddle, working perfectly, but on my localhost not working.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.text{
position:absolute;
left:25px;
top:13px;
    width:120px;    
   font-size:11px;
color:#fff;

}
._text{
font-size:11px;
color:#fff;


}
.container {
    position:relative;

background:#010101;
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**here is fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nju2ecby/3/)

Answer (score 1):

See this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nju2ecby/4/

I convert the span in div and for it I set the line-height the same of his container.

```
.text {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#fff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 150px;
}
._text {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#fff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 150px;
}
.container {
    background:#010101;
    width:450px;
    height:150px;
}
```